# DBCC CLONEDATABASE called from stored procedure fails

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

SQL Server 2019
DBCC CLONEDATABASE runs successfully when issued in a query window ... but when called from a stored procedure, fails with "User 'dbo' does not have permission to run DBCC CLONEDATABASE "

I want to give a user the ability to drop and "rebuild" their database...

The stored procedure is defined with the "EXEC AS Owner"  and resides in our _dba_utility database.
The "Owner" is a member of the sysadmin server role, and db_owner database role in the _dba_utility database and the database used for cloning..

What am I missing ?

```
Create procedure [dbo].[usp_rebuild_dev_database] as
Begin

    -- Drop the existing database
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'dev_database')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [dev_database] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
        DROP DATABASE [dev_database];
    END

    -- Clone the "EMPTY" database
    DBCC CLONEDATABASE ([_EMPTY_dev_database], [dev_database]) WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB;    

    ALTER DATABASE [dev_database] SET READ_WRITE;

    ALTER DATABASE [dev_database] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'_EMPTY_dev_database', NEWNAME = N'dev_database' );
    ALTER DATABASE [dev_database] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'_EMPTY_dev_database_log', NEWNAME = N'dev_database_log' );

End;
```

exec _dba_utility.dbo.usp_rebuild_dev_database;

returns..  User 'dbo' does not have permission to run DBCC CLONEDATABASE.

Comment: "The stored procedure is defined with the ""EXEC AS Owner"". I don't see that un your proc code.

Answer (score 0):

> The "Owner" is a member of the sysadmin server role

Nope.  The owner is dbo, a database-level principal.

> OWNER
>
> Specifies the statements inside the module executes in the
> context of the current owner of the module. If the module does not
> have a specified owner, the owner of the schema of the module is used.
> OWNER cannot be specified for DDL or logon triggers.

[CREATE PROCEDURE - EXECUTE AS CLAUSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: OK, ...  changed the EXECUTE AS to   EXECUTE AS 'SQLDBA'    SQLDBA is a SQL login and a member of the sysadmin role and db_owner role in the all databases..  and I still get the error ...  User 'SQLDBA' does not have permission to run DBCC CLONEDATABASE

Comment: That's executing as the _user_ SQLDBA, which again is a database principal.  I believe this scenario requires signing the procedure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Ollie2308, `EXECUTE AS <user>` is sandboxed to the current database. Signing the proc as David suggested is the way to go.